# ASP.NET GridView Row Methods Counterparts in WinForms DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Are there any [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET) GridView's `RowCreated`, `RowDataBound` counterpart methods?

All I want is to break a string into lines before displaying. I've put `Environment.NewLine` to create a line break but have no success till now. So I think I need to `RowCreated` or `RowDataBound`, etc. events to make modifications.

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be better to just preprocess the data?